# Is the following bash script correct?

Tags: bash, shell

what's wrong in the following code?

```
while read -r -u 3 line1 && read -r -u 4 line2
do 
    if [ $line2 = "moon" ] #can i do this?
       echo "hi"
    fi
done 
done 3<file1 4<file2
```

`file1` and `file2` are text files and script is part of a larger scrit.  The error I am getting is `syntax error near unexpected token elif [[ "$line2" = "moon" ]]`.

Comment: Are you using single brackets or double brackets? If double brackets, make sure you script is run by `bash`; `sh` doesn't recognize the double-bracket expression. More generally, your error message doesn't match the code you posted, which doesn't have an `elif` clause.

Comment: why is there two "done" at the end?

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ "$line2" = "moon" ]];
then 
echo "hi"
fi
```

Always quote string variables while doing string operation. 
And `[[ ]]` is a better option. 
Read about it [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash)

Comment: line2 is a variable not a string

Comment: @user2613272, it's still an interpreted variable whether or not it has those quotes. The quotes protect against problems sometimes encountered with empty strings.

Comment: The conditional expression doesn't require parameter expansions to be quoted, as it doesn't perform word expansion in that setting.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of script? The script can only be verified against a specification. Does it do what you want? Does it give you an error?

The main issues I see if that you are reading from two files but only using the second. It's seems your script could be replaced by:

```
$ grep -qF "moon" file2 && echo "hi"
```

Comment: actually , it's part of my script ,it's part of elif so the error is syntax error near unexpected token elif [[ "$line2" = "moon" ]]

Comment: And we are meant to know that how? This kind of information is necessary, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking B.T.W The error message you post doesn't match the script you posted!?